# How to hardcode mesh objects as python variable declarations

Tags: python, add-on, bmesh

I am doing an addon, and I need to load constantly some premade objects to reproduce and edit it, I through that making the data directly avaliable from python would help to build fast bmesh variants.
But how I can convert an Bmesh data into an raw text and reverse it.

Comment: easiest hack solution: store vertex-coordinates, edges (as index-tuples of start-vertex and end-vertex), and faces (as indices of all contained vertices) in three lists. Then, on demand, create a mesh, fill it with mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces). create your bmesh and load your mesh, then delete the mesh.

Comment: **as @Teck-freak , you can export the vertices.co and the edges and/or faces
here and example about expor mesh data to TXT** [http://pasteall.org/51127/python](http://pasteall.org/51127/python) **and here some example about how to use this data into and Add-on in order to add new mesh** [http://pasteall.org/693657/python](http://pasteall.org/693657/python) I can not add the code here because overload the text limit :(

Comment: [Related](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?210351-Mesh-to-script-helper&p=1797752&viewfull=1#post1797752)